# How to pass parameters in a POST() request using the new HTTP client in Java

Tags: java, rest, http

I just started using the [new HTTP client](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/package-summary.html) in Java and I'm unsure on how to pass parameters for a PUT request.

The specific request I'm dealing with requires an `Authentication` token and a parameter `type`.

- I've successfully dealt with the `Authentication` token using `.headers()`
- I tried to do the same thing with the `type` parameter but I get an error message that states I haven't passed a `type` field.

```
HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder().build();
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(URI.create("...")) # The API url
                .headers("Authorization", token, "type", "type 1")
                .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.noBody())
                .build();

HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request,HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
System.out.println(response.body());
```

Comment: Is the `type` parameter expected to be a header? isn't it a query parameter... `URI.create("...?type=type1")`?

Comment: Thank you so much... If I had multiple parameters, how would I do it? would it be like `URI.create("...?param1 = ... ? param2 = ...)`

Comment: `?type=type1&param2=value2&param3=value3&param4=value4`

Comment: Thank you so much... Is there a way I can turn your comments into an answer?

Comment: Your question needs to be made clearer first and then you can answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ernest_k commented, we can pass parameters through by appending them to the end of the URL in this format: `?type=type1&param2=value2&param3=value3&param4=value4`

```
HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder().build();
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(URI.create("..." + "?type=type 1"))
                .headers("Authorization", token)
                .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.noBody())
                .build();

HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request,HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
System.out.println(response.body());
```